# Some images are showing and some are not showing on imageView Captured by camera Android

Tags: imageview, android-camera, android-bitmap

I am new in android can anybody tell me the reason that why some images are not showing on imageView?
Please tell me how to set all size images on imageview.

Comment: Please add some examples to your question - it is hard to understand problem right now.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: I have an ImageView and I want to capture Image from camera intent and show the result on the imageView. When i capture the image only small size images are show on the imageview and Large size images are not showing. When I test the app on other device then it works properly only the Samsung Galaxy Note 3 N-900 device is creating problem.